# Каково происхождение слова "князь" и почему его нет в других языках?

Tags: этимология

Все остальные дворянские титулы такие, как "граф", "принц" и т. д. — общие для большинства европейских языков, и только титула "князь" в западных странах нет, а на английский это переводится как prince. Так каково происхождение слова "князь" и почему его нет в других языках?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

По сути первоначально ПРИНЦ и КНЯЗЬ обозначали приблизительно одно и то же: предводителя. Просто эти слова имеют разное происхождение. Слово **КНЯЗЬ** («предводитель войска и правитель области в феодально-удельной Руси») пришло в русский язык из др.-герм. языков. Др.-в.-нем. kuning — «предводитель рода, племени» > «вождь воен. дружины» — образовано с пом. суф. -ing от *kuni «род» (ср. литерат. нем. **König «король»**). Слово **ПРИНЦ** в русском языке появилось во времена Петра I, происходит оно от лат. рrinсерs (рrimо-сарs "занимающий первое место"). В других языках слово "князь" существует: в немецком  König, в норвежском - konge, в шведском - kung. Для германских языков слово является исконным и значит - 'король'. А собственно титул "князь" обозначается в этих языках заимствованным словом - prince.
Вообще система титулов и их наименований - широкая тема, можно много говорить.