# Князь - этимология

Tags: этимология, заимствования

Здравствуйте!

Услышав обращение к князю "Светлейший", неожиданно пришла мысль: у татар и, наверное, у всех тюрских народов, есть выражение кон ягы, что означает сторона или место света, что очень напоминает слово княгиня, и скандинавское конунг. Потом посмотрел историю города в Турции Конья. Этот город называли священным. Греки его называли Иконион, что похоже  на слово икона. Кстати, и французский Коньяк тоже может быть такого происхождения.

Скажите пожалуйста, может ли это быть так?

Comment: Здесь нет абсолютного дубликата. Вопрос поставлен немного по-другому. Другое дело, что по ссылке есть ответ на оба вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Князь - от герм. konung, которое в свою очередь произошло от ПИЕ ĝene̯- "рождать". Ср. ПИЕ формы ***ĝene̯os*** семья, ***ĝne̯tos*** рожденный ***ĝene̯tor*** родоначальник и т.д.

Иконион - от ПИЕ корня ***a̯ei̯-*** "копия", "имитация", "сходство". Ср. ПИЕ формы ***a̯eima̯*** "копия" ***a̯iq̆ea̯lis*** "такой же, одинаковый", ***a̯eimos*** "имитация, замена".

Answer (score 0):

Корень "кон" **очень** древний. Происхождение - скифское (или, даже - "до-скифское"). С учётом того, что зона расселения скифов полностью покрывает предположительные пути миграции легендарных "индоевропейцев", а позднее оказалась захвачена тюркоязычными племенами - возможны любые "чудеса".

Answer (score 0):

Князь - от konung.
Обсуждалось уже на форуме.
Здесь посмотрите. [Каково происхождение слова "князь" и почему его нет в других языках?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/4971/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8C)

Ответ там более чем исчерпывающий.

Помнится, и еще была как минимум одна схожая тема. Так что, если поискать...
//===
Связь со скифами и прочие версии выглядят более чем натянутыми.

Comment: Тут не совсем "повтор".

Answer (score 0):

Я читал, что у слова "князь" есть две версии происхождения:

1. От "кнез" - вождь племени у первобытных славян.
2. От слов: "кон" - закон, "яз" - я. Буквально означает: "я - закон".